# Two versions of a package installed

Tags: apt, package-management

I have two versions of polybar installed. Running `polybar -v` I get 3.5.0-12. `which polybar` gives */usr/local/bin/polybar*. I am guessing I installed this outside of apt maybe (its been over a year since I used this PC).

But another version through apt is installed too, version *3.5.5 at /usr/bin/polybar*

---

How do I go about removing the older version and make sure the one from apt repo is used? I honestly can't tell which version is running now (possibly the older one since it is getting invoked when calling `polybar`).

PS: Could I just delete the one in */usr/local/bin* and reinstall one from apt? I've seen this recommended in some deb packages like `go` although it feels asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version in `/usr/local/bin/polybar` has most definitely not been installed via `apt`. `/usr/local/bin` is the location for software which is not part of your distribution, notably self-compiled software. Software installed via `apt` will normally go to `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

Just removing the manually installed version is indeed the recommended way of resolving this.
That may however comprise more than just the file `/usr/local/bin/polybar`, for example libraries under `/usr/local/lib`, a man page under `/usr/local/man` or additional files under `/usr/local/share`.
You may want to look around in your download folder(s) whether you can find the installation archive for that version. Its filename will probably start with `polybar`, possibly contain the version number `3.5.0-12`, and end in an archive extension like `.tar.gz`, `.tgz` or similar. Inspect it to find out which files it may have installed and where.

To avoid breaking anything irrevocably you may start by renaming `/usr/local/bin/polybar` instead of removing it, for example:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/polybar /usr/local/bin/polybar.DELETEME
```

But again, check what other files belong to the program, and rename them, too.
Then check if the `polybar` command now runs the correct version successfully.
If it does, you can actually delete the bad version with:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/polybar.DELETEME
```

and so on for the other renamed files.

Comment: Moved `polybar` and `polybar-msg` under /usr/local/bin and the latest from apt started working. I'll reinstall it if there is any other issue. As for removing the files I have the git repo cloned but not sure I ever built and installed from source. I'll look into how to properly uninstall it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to administrate your system more carefully. Inspection of `/usr/local` is recommended as a first step.

To fix the current situation just run single command to remove locally installed Polybar:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/polybar
```

and then use `polybar` from [official deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=impish&section=all&arch=any&keywords=bin%2Fpolybar&searchon=contents), you can reinstall it at any time by
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall polybar` .

Comment: Yup, the newer version took over once the manually installed file was renamed. BTW what do you mean by better administrate? Be aware of what and where I install? I am trying to learn and understand what I have in my PC. For now though I mostly install from the terminal and use Synaptic manager to look into whats installed. Looking forward to learning the proper functions.